# Intersection of two closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was solving a question on leetcode. I noticed that they defined the intersection of two closed intervals as so:

$$[a,b]\cap [c,d] = \left[\max(a,c), \min(b,d)\right]$$

The leetcode question can be found [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/interval-list-intersections/). I am wondering if there is a formal proof for this? I know that the intersection of two closed intervals yields a closed interval in what I have studied in real analysis but I never came across (or don't remember) this definition.

Any suggestions or references are appreciated.

Comment: That's valid if $\max(a,c)\le\min(b,d)$, otherwise the intersection is empty.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Isn't it still valid then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proof is as easy as filling in the definitions:

\begin{align}
x\in[a,b]\quad&\text{if and only if}\quad a\leq x\text{ and }x\leq b\\
x\in[c,d]\quad&\text{if and only if}\quad c\leq x\text{ and }x\leq d\\
&\quad\Downarrow\\
x\in[a,b]\cap[c,d]\quad&\text{if and only if}\quad a\leq x\text{ and }c\leq x\text{, and }x\leq b\text{ and }x\leq d\\
&\text{if and only if}\quad \max\{a,c\}\leq x\text{ and }x\leq \min\{b,d\}\\
&\text{if and only if}\quad x\in[\max\{a,c\},\min\{b,d\}]\\
\end{align}